# SQL Query - FULL JOIN multiple tables but return NULL results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL Query - FULL JOIN multiple tables but return NULL results

Good day!

Need help with my sql query code;

- first FULL JOIN **"ILEtransfer"** no NULL result
- but im getting NULL result once i add a FULL JOIN **"ILEmsales"**

Thank you in advance!

here's my sql query code;

```
     ;WITH Barcodes AS
 (
 SELECT
     [BBI$Barcodes].[Item No_]
     ,[BBI$Barcodes].[Description]
     ,[BBI$Barcodes].[Variant Code]
 FROM [BBI$Barcodes]
 ),
 ILEtransfer AS
 (
 SELECT
     [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code] AS [Location]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
     ,MAX([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Description]) AS [Description]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
     ,SUM([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Quantity]) AS [Delivery]
    
 FROM [BBI$Item Ledger Entry]
 WHERE
     [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]='HPGW'
     AND [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type] = '4'
 GROUP BY
     [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
 ),
 ILEmsales AS
 (
 SELECT
     [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code] AS [Location]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
     ,MAX([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Description]) AS [Description]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
     ,SUM([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Quantity]) AS [MSales]
    
 FROM [BBI$Item Ledger Entry]
 WHERE
     [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]='HPGW'
     AND [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type] = '1'
     AND [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Document No_] NOT LIKE 'HP%'
 GROUP BY
     [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
 )
 SELECT DISTINCT
         BAR.[Item No_] AS [Item No_]
         ,BAR.[Description] AS [Description]
         ,BAR.[Variant Code] AS [Variant Code]
         ,ISNULL(ILETR.[Delivery],0) AS [Delivery]
         ,ISNULL(ILEMS.[MSales],0) AS [Sales]
    
 FROM [BBI$Barcodes] BAR
    
 FULL JOIN [ILEtransfer] ILETR
 ON ILETR.[Item No_]=BAR.[Item No_]
 AND ILETR.[Variant Code]=BAR.[Variant Code]
    
 FULL JOIN [ILEmsales] ILEMS
 ON ILEMS.[Item No_]=BAR.[Item No_]
 AND ILEMS.[Variant Code]=BAR.[Variant Code]
    
 WHERE
 ILETR.[Location]='HPGW'
 AND ILETR.[Entry Type]='4'
 OR ILEMS.[Entry Type]='1'
```

**here's the sql query result;**

[SQL Query NULL result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euVHB.jpg)

Comment: You got a whole bunch of where clauses. How can we know if any of the individual sub-selects actually returns something? And if they do, wouldn't the where clause in the end take out the results? Also be careful of the operator precedence between `AND` and `OR`. Add parentheses when in doubt.

Comment: @GolezTrol

thank you for reply

should i add all the where clauses below the query code?

Comment: use INNER JOIN instead of FULL JOIN

Comment: I don't know what you _should_ do, since your data and your goal is not clear to me. Maybe you _should_ add an example to the question ;-)  (try [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). I just wanted to point out that it's probably not the joins themselves, but the where clauses that are eliminating the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the FULL JOIN to `ILEmsales` you get NULLs because there are rows in `ILEmsales` with `[Item No_]` and `[Variant Code]` which doesn't match rows in `[BBI$Barcodes]` (also satisfiying the WHERE conditions).
Update your query as below to know those values that are present in `ILEmsales` but not in `[BBI$Barcodes]` (check last 2 columns):

```
    ;WITH Barcodes AS
 (
 SELECT
     [BBI$Barcodes].[Item No_]
     ,[BBI$Barcodes].[Description]
     ,[BBI$Barcodes].[Variant Code]
 FROM [BBI$Barcodes]
 ),
 ILEtransfer AS
 (
 SELECT
     [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code] AS [Location]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
     ,MAX([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Description]) AS [Description]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
     ,SUM([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Quantity]) AS [Delivery]
    
 FROM [BBI$Item Ledger Entry]
 WHERE
     [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]='HPGW'
     AND [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type] = '4'
 GROUP BY
     [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
 ),
 ILEmsales AS
 (
 SELECT
     [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code] AS [Location]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
     ,MAX([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Description]) AS [Description]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
     ,SUM([BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Quantity]) AS [MSales]
    
 FROM [BBI$Item Ledger Entry]
 WHERE
     [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]='HPGW'
     AND [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type] = '1'
     AND [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Document No_] NOT LIKE 'HP%'
 GROUP BY
     [BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Location Code]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]
     ,[BBI$Item Ledger Entry].[Variant Code]
 )
 SELECT DISTINCT
         BAR.[Item No_] AS [Item No_]
         ,BAR.[Description] AS [Description]
         ,BAR.[Variant Code] AS [Variant Code]
         ,ISNULL(ILETR.[Delivery],0) AS [Delivery]
         ,ISNULL(ILEMS.[MSales],0) AS [Sales]
         -- Values to know not matching rows in [BBI$Barcodes]
         ,ILEMS.[Item No_] AS [Not matching Item No_]
         ,ILEMS.[Variant Code] AS [Not matching Variant Code]
 FROM [BBI$Barcodes] BAR
    
 FULL JOIN [ILEtransfer] ILETR
 ON ILETR.[Item No_]=BAR.[Item No_]
 AND ILETR.[Variant Code]=BAR.[Variant Code]
    
 FULL JOIN [ILEmsales] ILEMS
 ON ILEMS.[Item No_]=BAR.[Item No_]
 AND ILEMS.[Variant Code]=BAR.[Variant Code]
    
 WHERE
 ILETR.[Location]='HPGW'
 AND ILETR.[Entry Type]='4'
 OR ILEMS.[Entry Type]='1'
```